# NetBeans 12.4 - Spring Boot Maven project, debug all test

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3, junit5, netbeans-12

In a Spring Boot Maven project I have tests with `JUnit 5`.
Within a test class (annotated with `@SpringBootTest`) I can select

```
Test File
Debug Test File
Run Focused Test Method
Debug Focused Test Method
```

On the project itself (`Files` window) I can select

```
Test
```

which runs all tests.

Is there a way to debug all tests?
So to speak I would expect a selection on the project like `Debug Test` besides `Test`.

The reason is, that some errors appear only when I run all tests. But when I run or debug just the erroneous test method or even the whole test class, the errors don't appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I haven't found a more GUI-friendly way yet (and verified only on Netbeans 12.3), but:

a) If you already have a `nbactions.xml`:

Add the following to the `<actions/>` element:

```
<action>
  <actionName>CUSTOM-Debug-all-tests</actionName> <!-- should be unique for this project -->
  <displayName>Debug All Tests</displayName> <!-- will be displayed in context menu -->
  <packagings>
    <packaging>*</packaging> <!-- according to your needs, taken from pre-configured action -->
  </packagings>
  <goals> <!-- according to your needs, taken from pre-configured action -->
    <goal>process-test-classes</goal>
    <goal>surefire:test</goal>
  </goals>
  <properties> <!-- according to your needs, taken from pre-configured action -->
    <forkMode>once</forkMode>
    <maven.surefire.debug>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address} 
    </maven.surefire.debug>
    <jpda.listen>true</jpda.listen>
  </properties>
</action>
```

(Of course you can modify & adjust it to your needs, but this works for a quickstart (maven) project. Also interesting: "Debug integration test" action!)

Then you can execute it from "Project context menu>Run Maven>Debug All Tests"!

---

b) If You don't have an `nbactions.xml` (in your project) yet:

Just modify one of the pre-configured "Actions" (preferably "Debug (Integration) Test") from the "Actions" menu of "Project Properties", this (hitting "OK") will generate the according file at your project root. Then you can make it (maven-) executable as described above (a).(There *must/should* also be a way to run these Actions without modifying `nbactions.xml` [at least by implementing a custom plugin](https://netbeans.apache.org/wiki/DevFaqActionAddProjectTypePopUp.asciidoc)....but haven't found the action/menu/tab yet:))

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to modify the XML file directly, just

- choose the `Actions` category in `Project Properties`
- choose `Configuration` (`<default config>`, or `dev (Profile)`, or...)
- click `Add Custom` button
- enter `Action Name`
- fill the fields `Execute Goals`, `Set Properties`, etc.

If `<default config>` is choosen from `Configuration`, `NetBeans` will create a file `nbactions.xml`, otherwise if for example `dev (Profile)` is choosen a file `nbactions-dev.xml` is created, and so on.

The custom action is available in the context menue under `Run Maven` opened on `pom.xml`